# Alternative to eval() for interpolating dynamic variable reference?

Tags: ruby

In the following code:

```
def solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2)
    #score index:  0 = james, 1 = sam
    score = Array.new(2, 0)
    calcScore = lambda do |x,y| 
        if ( x > y )
            score[0] += 1
        end
        if ( x < y )
            score[1] += 1       
        end
    end
    0.upto 2 do |index|
        calcScore.call(eval("a#{index}"),eval("b#{index}"))
    end
    score
end
```

Is there a more eloquent DRY way to achieve the dynamic variable reference without using:

`eval("a#{index}")`

Comment: binding.local_variable_get is your best friend.

Comment: so basically 
 
`binding.local_variable_get` is the safe  eval() ?

Comment: No. Its the safe local variable getting:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` is evil. Don't use it. Here's an equivalent code, which should work for any number of scores. It uses the fact that `a <=> b` returns `-1`, `0` or `1`.

Your input format isn't very convenient. This code uses `each_slice` and transpose to transform `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` into `[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]`. You can then iterate over the games to calculate the total score:

```
def calc_score(a, b)
  [[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1]][a <=> b]
end

def solve(*scores)
  size = scores.size
  raise 'Need an even number of scores' unless size.even?
  raise 'Need at least two scores' unless size > 0
  scores.each_slice(size / 2).to_a.transpose.inject([0, 0]) do |(a_total, b_total), (a, b)|
    a_score, b_score = calc_score(a, b)
    [a_total + a_score, b_total + b_score]
  end
end
```

or even shorter :

```
def solve(*scores)
  size = scores.size
  raise 'Need an even number of scores' unless size.even?
  raise 'Need at least two scores' unless size > 0
  scores.each_slice(size / 2).to_a.transpose.map do |a, b|
    calc_score(a, b)
  end.transpose.map{ |s| s.inject(:+) } # .map(&:sum) in Ruby 2.4
end
```

As an example:

```
solve(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
# [0, 3]
solve(2, 0, 0, 3)
# [1, 1]
```

Comment: Oh wow, I really hadn't thought of transpose o.o
I'm sorry for the broad question, I wish there was a way to select multiple answers.  

My original intent was to practice with lambdas and finding a way to interpolate variable references, but your solution is very creative and elegant. Kudos.  

Selecting this as an answer to encourage other readers to follow what I believe is the ruby way(even though I didn't come to it).  The other answers are also correct, so I do apologize for the broad question.

Comment: Nice! `to_a` is redundant before `transpose`, also `0` is redundant in `inject`. Also a slightly more ruby way to write that would be `scores.each_slice(size / 2).transpose.map(&calc_score).transpose.map { |s| s.inject(:+) }`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: No, yes, no. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

While `local_variable_get` and `eval` could seem to do their job here, the right approach would be:

```
def solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2)
  a, b = [a0, a1, a2], [b0, b1, b2]
  # deal with score
  0.upto 2 do |index|
    calcScore.call(a[index], b[index])
  end
  score
end
```

Or, better and more DRY:

```
def solve(*as_and_bs)
  raise unless as_and_bs.size == 6
  a, b = as_and_bs(0..2), as_and_bs(3..5)
  # deal with score
  0.upto 2 do |index|
    calcScore.call(a[index], b[index])
  end
  score
end
```

Comment: Or hash with a and b as keys.

Comment: Also would be great and showily to use `each_slice` (with initial transforming arguments)

Comment: I'd stick with #1, assuming the arguments are not to be changed. Also, `*as_and_bs` doesn't guard against the wrong number of arguments being passed. In a redesign one could have `solve(a,b)` where caller passes two arrays.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that’s why there is `raise` guarding against the wrong number of parameters.

Comment: Didn't notice that. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

Use `binding.local_variable_get`:

```
 0.upto 2 do |index|
   calcScore.call(binding.local_variable_get("a#{index}"),
                  binding.local_variable_get("b#{index}"))
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you combine a1, a2, and a3 into an array and do the same thing with b, then you can use regular `[]` indexing:

```
def solve(a, b)
    #score index:  0 = james, 1 = sam
    score = Array.new(2, 0)
    calcScore = lambda do |x,y| 
        if ( x > y )
            score[0] += 1
        end
        if ( x < y )
            score[1] += 1       
        end
    end
    0.upto 2 do |index|
        calsScore.call(a[index], b[index])
    end
    score
end
```

You could also add a custom error checking for the array lengths:

```
raise(ArgumentError) unless [a,b].all? { |arr| arr.length == 3 }
```